# Any good lightweight date/time picker for web with good UI?

Tags: jquery, datetime, jquery-ui

A few wishes:

- If it is jQuery based, best.
- If it focuses on easy UI rather than eye candy,
  better.
- If it is both a date and time picker,
  good.

I should mention that I've already looked at most options available that I can find using Google.

The problem is not that there's not a single date+time picker included in the official jQuery-UI project so some are for older versions of jQuery, some have ugly UI choices, and one which has a somewhat good UI seems buggy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Datepicker:

[jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Timepicker:

[timepickr plugin](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/)

Bonus points, both use the [jQuery UI Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Comment: Datepicker is awesome.  But might I suggest you just use simple drop downs for time picking?  Timepickr's interface is (IMHO) quite user-unfriendly and non-intuitive.

Comment: I agree, timepickr is overkill for what is probably best represented using three select lists: [HH][MM][AM|PM] or just [HH][MM].

Comment: I'm not able to see timepicker link (timeouts) but I will check back later. 
And Yes, my last option is two select based timepicker ;)

Answer (score 15):

I've found Trent Richardson's date/time picker to be good. It has a heap of options and seems to work well.

Available here: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

It's based on jQuery UI

Answer (score 5):

My Two Favourite for Clean UI:

## [DatePair](http://jonthornton.github.io/Datepair.js/)

*by [Jon Thornton](https://github.com/jonthornton)*

Take a look at [Jon Thornton](https://github.com/jonthornton)'s latest work, [DatePair](http://jonthornton.github.io/Datepair.js/), which is inspired by Google Calendar's clean UI. From what I've found it's by far the cleanest design and easiest to use.

#### Dates

[image: Date Selection]

#### Times

[image: Time Selection]

## [Pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/)

*by [Amsul](http://amsul.ca/)*

Amsul's [Pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) is super clean and responsive, so it works really well on mobile devices as well, consuming the full screen on small screens.

#### Dates

[image: Date Selection]

#### Times

[image: Time Selection]

Answer (score 3):

The [Any+Time(TM)](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) widget combines a date/time picker for a single input field with a wide variety of formats.  It now uses jQuery and supports jQuery UI Themes and CSS customization for complete visual integration into any website.  And if you encounter any bugs, just report them and expect a resolution in a matter of hours!

Comment: I was going to try this out, but the license is CC by-nc-sa so unfortunately I can't use it (working on a commerical product)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that has both, but its fully based on jquery [UI/Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) that lets the user select time HH:MM
Works with jquery-1.2.3.  [jQuery DateTimepicker](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DateTimepicker)

Answer (score 1):

Check this http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements#8
I also stumbled upon the following:
http://code.google.com/p/dyndatetime/
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post, but for future reference, I wanted to put this here:

[Calentim Date Time Picker Plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/calentim-date-time-range-picker/20099228)

- It's jQuery based, simple to modify
- UI based on SCSS file, dropdown or inline support for desktop, modal like support for mobile
- It's a date and time range picker, but you can disable the range feature, the time feature, so it can be used as a date range picker, or single date picker, or single date time picker etc.

Answer (score 0):

For my needs, this example is a great option.  It combines the jQuery datepicker with an easy-to-use time selector.

http://puna.net.nz/timepicker.htm#