# Javascript time helper? -Interesting problem!

Tags: javascript, time

I am new to the world of javascript and even trying google search has not really helped me find what I am looking for.

So I have come here in the hope you can point me in the right direction.

RULE= It must not be click! Can be done by tabbing!

I have many text fields which the user will input times that have been recorded.

E.g. Event 1 happened at 11:31am
     Event 2 happened at 11:59am

I want to make this process as easy as possible for the user by having the textbox formatted in hours and seconds in 24hr format:

So the textbox value= 00:00 and when the user selects the text box they can enter the hours part. Then it will jump to the seconds part.

Any idea if there is something that can do that if so could you link me. If not could you give me an idea of what the coding will be like and if there are easier alternatives.

I have made some pseudo code to help you understand my implementation goal:

```
for count = 0 , while count is less than 20, count++
{

create a texbox with name time+count, set the value to ="00:00"
}

when the user enters numbers they go into the hour segment until that is completed
the script then jumps the cursor to the minutes segment

if time+count+1 is lesser thatn time+count message user that time error "An event cannot occur before the previous event"
```

Thankyou for hearing me out!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879783/any-good-lightweight-date-time-picker-for-web-with-good-ui

Comment: to get you started, do a google search on "time picker"

Comment: Yes but that means my user has to click and select, rather than just tab and enter a time! :)

Comment: Google/Bing: Auto Tab JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know of any time pickers that would suit your needs, but here's a basic idea of how one would be implemented:

- You have two textboxes, or multiple pairs of textboxes
- In each textbox, you put an event handler to handle "onkeyup" event
- In onkeyup handler, check if lenght of text in box is 2

  - If length is 2 -> focus the next textbox

This way the user can simply keep on typing the numbers.

You may need to add some additional checks into the event listener, for example to make sure that if the user comes back to the field, they can edit it easily (eg. if they press shift-tab, it won't focus an incorrect field)

If you wanted to be really fancy, you could have a single textbox for times. Then, each time user presses a key, you'd check if it's a number. If user first types two numbers, it would then insert a `:` as the separator if the third key is a number, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a beginning. Using jQuery this is not such a painful task.

http://jsfiddle.net/sArjQ/

```
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var input = $("<input>", { name: 'time' + i, // create input element
                               val:  '00:00' });

    input.click(function() {

        $(this).prop({ selectionStart: 0, // move caret to beginning on click
                       selectionEnd:   0 });

    }).keydown(function() {

        var sel = $(this).prop('selectionStart'),
            val = $(this).val(),
            newsel = sel === 2 ? 3 : sel; // so that it moves two positions for :

        $(this).val(val.substring(0, newsel) // automatically set value
                    + val.substring(newsel + 1))

               .prop({ selectionStart: newsel, // move caret along
                       selectionEnd:   newsel });
    });

    $('body').append(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks any chance you could explain this function to help me understand?